# MacBook Pro: Android File Transfer, says "Could not connect" even though my Android phone gets the 'Allow' notification. Restarted needed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, android, file-transfer

MacBook Pro: Everytime I want to use the Android File Transfer, it says "Could not connect to Device. Try reconnecting or restarting your device" even though I am connected and my Android phone gets the 'Allow' notification and I allow it. I have to restart my computer each time with it connected.

Unless I restart my computer with the cable already connected, my Macbook doesn't recognize my android. This issue started a few months ago, was working fine before then. It's time consuming to need to restart my computer anytime I want to take files off of it.

This the intel macbook pro, running 13.1

The phone is a samsung A52, completely up to date with android 13

Comment: I am getting this problem too. I think it was easier just to email myself or use Google Drive, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry if I'm not solving your problem directly, but AFT has been super buggy for me too, I even tried OpenMTP and other alternatives to transfer files via a cable, but all of them face similar issues. So, I shifted to using Syncthing to directly sync my files from Android to Mac wirelessly. You can also try using Soduto on your MacOS device to send files wirelessly using KDE Connect. All of these applications are FOSS. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/z3d4ok/pixel_7_could_not_connect_to_device_error_usb/), I found that quitting Dropbox did the trick.

It seems some other apps in the background on your Mac are also trying to 'help' with USB, stopping Android File Transfer from doing so. So you need to quite those. Preview and OneDrive are others to quit from if you're still having problems.